# JavaScript callback sequence of operations

Tags: javascript

I am reading a book called **You don't know JS: Async and Performance**. They give the following example of a problem with nested callbacks and I was wondering if someone could elaborate on the specifics for me.

```
doA (function(){
    doC();
    doD(function(){
        doF();
    })
    doE();
});
doB();
```

According to the author, the code will execute in the order denoted alphabetically. Meaning doA, then doB ... . I may have been able to guess this based on experience, but I am trying to get a better grasp as to exactly why this happens.

Edit: I posted the question because the example in the book didn't make any sense to me and I was hoping to get some clarification. Maybe I should have just said that instead of trying to rescue the author with some explanation. I edited the question a little to try and make that clear.

Comment: The code you posted is invalid, you must be missing something (the `doA` call is never closed). Please check again and paste the full code.

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing how each of the functions invokes its callback. It's completely possible that they invoke them synchronously, in which case the order will be from top to bottom. This has nothing to do with an "event loop" or inner and outer "wrappers". These things have no meaning. It's entirely up to the implementation of each function.

Comment: Sorry, closed the function

Answer (score 0):

> Is it because the event loop runs for the entire outer "wrapper" first before it starts the inner wrapper?

No. If the order of execution really is A,B,C,D,E,F, then it is because that is how the functions are written to invoke their callbacks. If the functions were written differently, it could just as easily be A,C,D,E,F,B or A,C,D,F,E,B or, it could even just be A,B, if A does not accept a callback function.

All of this speculation...

> Here is what I think is happening. The event loop is first created as doA and doB because JavaScript is not really "concerned" with the contents of those lines at first. When JavaScript runs the line doA(function... it then adds the callback function to the end of the event loop placing doC and doD behind doB.

... is more or less nonsense.

Here is a drastically simplified example:

```
function doA(callback) { callback(); }

doA(function () {
  doB()
});
doC();
```

Here, the order is A,B,C because that is how A is written.

However, if we change `doA` so it invokes its callback asynchronously...

```
function doA(callback) { setTimeout(callback); }
```

... then the order changes completely to A,C,B.

This has **nothing to do** with JavaScript being "concerned" with any of the inner or outer code, or where *JavaScript* "chooses" to place the callbacks in the "event loop". These are not real things. JavaScript doesn't "choose" to do anything. It just executes your code. It's entirely about what each function does and whether the function accepts a callback and how that callback is invoked.